# Fortinet / VM connectivity issue

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 10 NUC.  I run Fortinet on it so that I can work on my company's LAN remotely.  On this Windows 10 machine I run VirtualBox, and I use an Ubuntu 16.04 VM.  I'm using the NAT setting in the VM.  I've seen several sites say that if Fortinet is running on the host I can work on the LAN from within the VM with no other configuration required.

It works, sort of, which is even more frustrating than when it doesn't work at all.  Sometimes, there are no problems.  Then, all of a sudden, the browser doesn't see the LAN sites but I can still ssh into my remote machine on the LAN.  Or, ssh fails but browsing still works.  Of course, there's my personal favorite where both fail.

Sometimes, I can restart Fortinet and the VM and things work, but it usually takes a few times for this scheme to work.  I have searched the web for others with similar issues with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: From the "/usr/share/resolvconf/dump-debug-info" command:

```
###### Start of debugging information for resolvconf ######
### ls -l /etc/resolvconf
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  511 Jun  3  2015 interface-order
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 26 19:06 resolv.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 26 18:58 update.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 26 19:02 update-libc.d
### cat /etc/resolvconf/interface-order
# interface-order(5)
lo.inet6
lo.inet
lo.@(dnsmasq|pdnsd)
lo.!(pdns|pdns-recursor)
lo
tun*
tap*
hso*
em+([0-9])?(_+([0-9]))*
p+([0-9])p+([0-9])?(_+([0-9]))*
@(br|eth)*([^.]).inet6
@(br|eth)*([^.]).ip6.@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(br|eth)*([^.]).inet
@(br|eth)*([^.]).@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(br|eth)*
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).inet6
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).ip6.@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).inet
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*
ppp*
*
### ls -l /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jun  3  2015 base
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 151 Jun  3  2015 head
### cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
### cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
### ls -l /run/resolvconf
### ls -l /run/resolvconf
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Aug 20 17:50 enable-updates
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Aug 20 17:51 interface
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 187 Aug 20 17:51 resolv.conf
### cat /run/resolvconf/enable-updates
### cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search PK5001Z
### ls -l /run/resolvconf/interface
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 36 Aug 20 17:51 NetworkManager
### cat /run/resolvconf/interface/NetworkManager
search PK5001Z
nameserver 127.0.1.1
### ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Mar  2 00:23 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
### lsattr /etc/resolv.conf
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf
### cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search PK5001Z
### cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
###### End of debugging information for resolvconf ######
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97668/discussion-on-question-by-nickelias-fortinet-vm-connectivity-issue).

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer so much as a debugging guide, but, after lots of back and forth in the comments...

1. We identified the issue was DNS related because `nslookup` was not working for corporate domain names.
2. We identified that resolveconf/dnsmasq was being used for DNS because nslookup was trying to use a `127.0.*.*` IP address as its DNS server.
3. We identified that resolveconf was using Network Manager as the DNS authority because `/usr/share/resolvconf/dump-debug-info` didn't contain any additional DNS entries.
4. We dumped the DNS servers configured for Network Manager by running `nmcli dev show | grep DNS`. We noticed that some DNS servers are added when VPN is reconnected.
5. We used `nslookup {dns-server-ip} {dns-server-ip}` to ask each DNS server to identify itself by hostname. We confimed that the new DNS server were for the corporate network.
6. We concluded that DNS servers were becoming de-synchronized between the VM and the Host. The guest would lose the corporate DNS servers even though VPN was still connected on the Host level. Subsequently, it would appear that the guest's access to the corporate network was 'broken' even though ping/ssh still worked correctly when using IPs or cached DNS entires.

Solutions:

- Manually add the DNS servers to network manager so they are not removed on incorrectly detected network changes. More information is here:
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/721080/